# Discord bot stopped working through Heroku, works fine offline

Tags: python, heroku, discord, bots

*Solved! Answer below.*

EDIT: Cleaned up this post to keep it all clear.

Here's the code for a simple GIF bot.
The important thing is: this bot works offline, gives a gif when I send a !command. This bot *comes* online with Heroku, so that is also good. What *doesn't* work is sending commands to receive gifs when the bot is online. So the code works, but I'm having trouble getting it in a working state with the commands in online mode.

**Code**

```
import random
import discord
import giphy_client
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from giphy_client.rest import ApiException

discord_token = *hidden for stackoverflow*

giphy_token = *hidden for stackoverflow*

api_instance = giphy_client.DefaultApi()

def search_gifs(query):
    try:
        return api_instance.gifs_search_get(giphy_token, query, limit=100, rating = 'PG13')

    except ApiException as e:
        return "Exception when calling DefaultApi->gifs_search_get: %s\n" % e

def gif_response(emotion):
    gifs = search_gifs(emotion)
    lst = list(gifs.data)
    gif = random.choices(lst)

    return gif[0].url

class DiscordClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Login as")
        print(self.user)
        print("-------")

    async def on_message(self, message):

        if message.author != self.user:
            if message.content == '!vibe':
                await message.channel.send(gif_response('vibing'))
            if message.content == '!dragony':
                await message.channel.send(gif_response('dragon'))  
            if message.content == '!gm':
                await message.channel.send(gif_response('gm'))    

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, guild_messages=True)
client = DiscordClient(intents=intents)
# client = DiscordClient()
client.run(discord_token)
```

**Requirements file (requirements.txt)**

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
PyNaCl==1.3.0
dnspython==1.16.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
pandas
giphy_client==1.0.0
```

**Procfile**

```
worker: python gif_bot.py
```

**Logs while deploying**

```
2022-04-21T11:46:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2022-04-21T11:47:14.667290+00:00 app[api]: Deploy x by user 
2022-04-21T11:47:14.667290+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user 
2022-04-21T11:47:15.800842+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-04-21T11:47:21.019690+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python gif_bot.py`
2022-04-21T11:47:21.640978+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-04-21T11:47:25.392719+00:00 app[worker.1]: Login as
2022-04-21T11:47:25.392731+00:00 app[worker.1]: Gif Bot#8552
2022-04-21T11:47:25.392732+00:00 app[worker.1]: -------
2022-04-21T11:47:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

Comment: You have just leaked tokens for Discord and Giphy, at least. Invalidate them _immediately_. Editing them out of your question is not enough. You have posted them on the Internet and they are forever compromised. Deleting your question is not enough, either.

Comment: @Chris I never expected something like this to happen... I deleted the post, realized certain people could still view it, edited the tokens out, but since I don't know how to chat to you if I delete the post again, could you some how private chat me (Discord, Twitter, anything) and explain how to invalidate the tokens... Please.

Comment: It will depend on the specific service, but in general, go to where you registered for API tokens in the first place on each service (Giphy and Discord), delete the ones that are there, and generate new ones.

Comment: @Chris Thank you so much. I went back to both places, did a reset for the tokens and generated new ones. Will never do this again...

Comment: It happens :-). I'm just glad you were able to reset them so quickly. But, yes, be careful with tokens. Treat them like passwords.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again, @Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@smerkd has helped me with the answer!

Adding "message_content = True" to the intents made it work.

**Code**

```
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, message_content=True, guilds=True, guild_messages=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of discord you need to pass your intents. Essentially telling discord what events you're going to be using and some cache stuff. A simple way to think of it is like what you're intending to do or permissions.

For your example try the following

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
```

Then fix your client to include the specified intents

```
client = DiscordClient(intents=intents)
```

Read up more about them here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

*Note:* you will have to add more intents if you're planning on doing anything more complicated.

Comment: I read about the intents and used your tips. My bot is working offline correctly (just opening the .py file), but fails to work properly from heroku. The bot is online though, but no commands work (only offline).

Comment: By offline do you just mean locally on your computer? So the on_message works/is called when you run the bot from your computer ?

Comment: Yeah, on_message works locally. @smerkd

Comment: That would be bizarre and I could only think of it as being a version difference with the default intents enabled. Try adding message_content = True to the intents.

Comment: You are a legend! I added "adding message_content = True" and that worked! I will answer this to my post and credit your for it. Appreciate it. @smerkd

Comment: No problem @Dragony. If this answered your question feel free to mark it as the solution. Thanks!